# Graph wont show in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm new to programming and trying to get a graph working in Python. But I'm stuck with some sort of error and the graph won't display. I'm on Ubuntu OS. Hope some Python gurus can explain what is wrong and how to fix it.

The code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



dates = []
prices = []

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFileReader)
         for row in csvFileReader:
            dates.append(int(row[0].split('-')[0]))
             prices.append(float(row[1]))
    return

 def predict_prices(dates, prices, x):
    dates = np.reshape(dates,(len(dates), 1))
    svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree = 2)
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf',C=1e3, gamma = 0.1)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_poly.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates, prices)

    plt.scatter(dates, prices, color='black', label='Data')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_rbf.predict(dates), color='red', label='RBF model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_lin.predict(dates), color='green', label='Linear 
model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_poly.predict(dates), color='blue', label='Polynomial 
model')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0], svr_poly.predict(x) 
[0]
get_data('aapl.csv')
predicted_price = predict_prices(dates, prices, 29)
print(predicted_price)
```

which results this error:

> /home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py:196:
>   FutureWarning: The default value of gamma will change from 'auto' to 'scale' in version 0.22 to account better for unscaled features. Set gamma explicitly to 'auto' or 'scale' to avoid this warning.

Comment: The "error" you show above is actually a warning from sklearn. It does not affect the working of your code in any way. The plots not showing up is a different error altogether. Show the full code with data samples so that we can try to reproduce that. Also showing the details about your system, OS, library versions may help/

Answer (score 0):

I have across this situation once, i.e. plots not showing up. In my case it had to do with the backend that matplotlib was using.

To check the selected backend you can try this:

```
 matplotlib.get_backend()
```

With the typical installation of matplotlib as good default backend is usually already set but depending on your operating system and you specific use case you may need to choose a different setting.

For example, in my current installation on ubuntu 18.04 I am using the 'Qt5Agg' backend.

You can always find more information in the official documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

**Copying** from the above link:

> There are four ways to configure your backend. If they conflict each
>   other, the method mentioned last in the following list will be used,
>   e.g. calling use() will override the setting in your matplotlibrc.

The backend parameter in your matplotlibrc file

```
backend : WXAgg   # use wxpython with antigrain (agg) rendering
```

Setting the MPLBACKEND environment variable, either for your current shell or for a single script:

```
export MPLBACKEND="module://my_backend"
python simple_plot.py

MPLBACKEND="module://my_backend" python simple_plot.py
```

To set the backend for a single script, you can alternatively use the -d command line argument (deprecated):

```
python script.py -dbackend
```

If your script depends on a specific backend you can use the use() function:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('PS')
```

Comment: "TkAgg" what should I put in the code to make it work?